# How can I disable future dates in the Silverlight DatePicker control

Tags: silverlight, datepicker

I need to be able to disable the selection of future dates within the Silverlight DatePicker control - any ideas ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datepicker.displaydateend(VS.95).aspx

```
DatePicker.DisplayDateEnd = DateTime.Now;
```

?

Comment: Anyone having an idea of how that could be set in XAML?

Comment: @Anttu DisplayDateEnd="{Binding Source={x:Static System:DateTime.Today}, Mode=OneWay}"

Comment: @KBoek Found the code where I used this and tried your XAML variant. Worked like a charm! Btw, DateTime.Now have been used instead of Today in the examples.

Answer (score 1):

Use the MaxDate to Blackout the future dates

System.DateTime DatesDisplayEnd = today.Add(duration);
System.DateTime MaxDate = DateTime.MaxValue;

stkDatePicker.BlackoutDates.Add(new CalendarDateRange(DatesDisplayEnd, MaxDate));